# Mercurial File hgwebdir.cgi is missing

Tags: pi-2

I have installed mercurial with

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

However if I try to do

```
sudo -u www-data cp hgwebdir.cgi /var/hg
```

I get the following error message

```
cp: cannot stat 'hgwebdir.cgi' no such file or directory
```

If I do a search for the file it can not be found.

Why can I not find this file? Should it have been installed with mercurial?

Comment: You could download it here http://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/raw-file/tip/hgwebdir.cgi

Comment: It only has hgweb.cgi not hgwebdir.cgi...

Comment: Also I get the error "error: revision not found: hgweb.cgi" if I put hgweb.cgi in the URL

Comment: Ok I managed to get the hgweb.cgi file but the hgwebdir.cgi is not there

Comment: Actually I am not sure the copy command I am using is correct as I can't seem to copy anything (even files I know exist (eg in the downloads folder). I used "$ sudo -u www-data cp hgwebdir.cgi /var/hg" is this correct?

Comment: Please read the instructions under bullet 3.(2) https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories .